# jQuery remove class on btns to add on btn clicked

Tags: jquery, class

I have a jsfiddle here - http://jsfiddle.net/03xck9tr/1/

It's a simple list of a links

When one is clicked I want to add a class 'selected' to that btn.

I need to remove the 'selected' class from previous btns that were clicked.

This sort of works but it removes the class adds it then removes it again.

```
    $(function(){
        $('.js-btn').on('click', function(){
            $('.js-btn').removeClass('js-btn-selected');
            $(this).Class('js-btn-selected');
        })
    })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do it in one line as

```
 $('.js-btn').not(this).removeClass('js-btn-selected');
```

Comment: This also means you would have to have the `js-btn-selected` class on the item once you write the html.

Comment: @stack_bloom , correctly said , but in @@ OP's condition it is done by some other event bound function

Answer (score 5):

You used a `.Class` jquery property that does not excist. Use `.addClass()`;

```
$(function(){
    $('.js-btn').on('click', function(){
        $('.js-btn').removeClass('js-btn-selected');
        $(this).addClass('js-btn-selected');

        //adding this here because it's a link
        return false;
    })
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/03xck9tr/2/

Answer (score 3):

```
$(function(){
    $('.js-btn').on('click', function(){
        $('.js-btn').removeClass('js-btn-selected');
        $(this).addClass('js-btn-selected');
    })
})
```

You need addClass to make it selected as you want.

Answer (score 1):

This is a better way since you only iterate over buttons that have .js-btn-selected. Which is only going to be 1 of course :)

```
$(function(){
        $('.js-btn').on('click', function(){
            $('.js-btn-selected').removeClass('js-btn-selected');
            $(this).addClass('js-btn-selected');
        })
    })
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KdmPww